# Is a man allowed to waste his seed for medical reasons?

Tags: halacha, medicine, sexuality

Is a man allowed to waste his seed for medical reasons, for example if a couple is having difficulty conceiving and the fertility specialists are requesting a sample.

Comment: Why do you call that wasting? It sounds like he's using it.

Comment: I am under the impression that all non vaginal or anal ejaculation is forbidden

Comment: Are you asking or telling?

Comment: Harav Mordechai Eliyahu writes (Darchei Halacha 151) that anytime one must waste seed for medical things he has to consult his Rav (IIRC).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Sefer Nishmat Avraham- Even Haezer Siman 23 this very question is asked. The Tzitz Eliezer sums up as follows: A husband may produce sperm for examination after his wife has been thoroughly tested. However the way the sperm should be *halachically* obtained is as follows:

1) The simplest way would be a post-coital sample; this would be permitted by almost all poskim.

2) If this is not possible or unsatisfactory, it should be obtained by coitus interruptus(as preferred by the Zekan Aharon).

3) If this is technically difficult, a condom can be worn during coitus; other poskim, however prefer this to coitus interruptus(among them Rav Auerbach zt'l)

4) If this is also not possible for whatever reason, it may be obtained by masturbation. Preferably, the doctor should obtain it using an instrument, but if this is not possible, the husband may obtain it himself.(This is the ruling of the Ahiezer but it is forbidden by the Igrot Moshe)

In regard to how long a couple must wait before the Husband's sperm may be examined: The Minchat Yitzchak writes that this may only been done after ten years of marriage; the Igrot Moshe writes five years; whereas the Chazon Ish was said to have permitted it after two years.

Comment: Perhaps a little more elaboration on the location of the sources?

Comment: @Yirmeyahu I put in the specific Siman. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Yes, although the precise locations of the poskim cited therein wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: I currently don't have the ability to type in Hebrew and the sources are locations to the book of the Posek where his ruling is written in Hebrew. If I find a way around this I will post the sources.

Comment: Although I think transliterations and numerals could get around that problem I think if you turn that comment into a question you may find a solution that works for you, the question is whether to do so here, in META, or on a related stackexchange.

Comment: Although this answer is fine, it can't be the only answer.  Please, if this question has practical significance to you, your rabbi.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I couldn't agree more. In situations like this, CYLOR

Comment: You omitted the Tzitz Eliezer who rules that there is no specific number of years and it all depends on the circumstances (and that he thinks the Chazon Ish agrees to this)

Comment: "other poskim, however prefer this to coitus interruptus(among them Rav Auerbach zt'l)" I think you mean R Feinstein not R Auerbach. I think you are misunderstanding R Auerbach's problem with coitus interruptus: he would prefer just Kiruv Basar without Hakhnasat HaEiver as the non-condom option so there is no active Maaseh Hotzaah. He's not saying therefore condom is better than that, just that Kiruv Basar outside is better than full coitus interruptus.

Comment: IIRC, for those needing to resort to a condom to obtain a sample, there’s a special condom that has no spermicide, and also has a small hole in the tip. This would be more lenient than the standard condom.

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52118&st=&pgnum=190